# Viscosity of different fluids

Tags: classical-mechanics, viscosity

Why is the viscosity of mercury almost equal to that of water at room temperature even though the density of mercury is 13 times greater than water's density?

Why does water viscosity decrease very fast at increasing temperatures while than of mercury remains almost constant?

Answer (score 1):

The viscosity similarity is coincidence.   Mercury atoms are held by metallic (covalent) bonds, while water molecules interact by hydrogen bonding, and by ionic bonding.

The density difference is not important.  Mercury's density results not from the outer electrons that determine viscosity forces, but from the heavy nucleus in the center of the atoms; density (grams per cubic centimeter) is not as important as particle number density (molecules per cubic centimeter), and
mercury has  4.05E22 atoms/cc while water  has 3.34E22 molecules/cc.   The number densities are similar.

The forces, though, that give rise
to viscosity in water are very complex, including ionization (really, partial decomposition) of the molecules, electrical polarization, shape interactions, and hydrogen bonding.  Mercury is simpler, just identical spheres with a few shared
electrons (that make metallic covalent bonding).

Water is liquid only in the narrow
range 0-100C, while mercury is liquid from -39 to +357 C.
It isn't surprising that water viscosity varies more with temperature
than mercury does.  It's a less stable liquid.